# Composite datawindow to txt

Tags: powerbuilder, composite, datawindow

I have built a composite datawindow in Powerbuilder 11.5 that presents the
invoice form of my application.
As most fiscal papers here in Greece, I have to send it as
a text file to a fiscal device that composes a digital tax
signature that I then append to the invoice.
The problem is that the `SaveAsAscii` function saves only the
first child datawindow and not the whole composite!
As you can understand this is a  serious issue.

Is there a way that I can use the SaveAsAscii on every
nested datawindow and produce separate text files?
I can then easily merge them in one text file and send it to
the fiscal device.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Install the Windows "Generic/Text only" printer and redirect the printing a file.

```
dw_1.object.DataWindow.Print.filename = 'c:\temp\test.txt'
dw_1.print()
```